# the length statement in SAS?

Tags: sas

The following is a simple SAS program:

```
libname learn = 'c:\books\learning';
data learn.test_scores;
  length ID $ 3 Name $ 15;
  input ID $ Score1-Score3;
  label ID ='student ID';
        Score1='Math Score';
        Score2='Science Score';
        Score3='English Score';
datalines;
1 90 95 98
2 78 77 75
3 88 91 92
;
```

My question is about the length statement. So, what exactly does Name $15 mean? Where is the variable Name? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length statement you have will define two variables. ID is defined as a character variable with room for maximum of 3 characters (bytes). And NAME is defined as character with room for a maximum of 15 characters.

Nowhere in your program do you assign any values to the variable NAME so it will be blank for all observations.

Note that you also have too many semi-colons in your LABEL statement.  This will cause the last three lines of it to be interpreted as attempts to assign character constants to the numeric variables SCORE1, SCORE2 and SCORE3. This will cause an error message and the values of these variables will all be missing.

Answer (score 0):

The Name is a variable name which is a character type and has a maximum length of 12 bytes.
(in PDV Name variable always take 12 bytes irrespective of the number of character in name variable)